# debugger-x for php how to listen in two locations

Tags: php, debugging, centos, vagrant, netbeans-8

Hi and thanks for any insight in advance.

This is my scenario.
I am using NetBeans +8.0
I am using vagrant w/ centos

In the vagrant file I have two locations that are being mapped (synced_folder)

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../source/www", "/var/www/html/public_html"
config.vm.synced_folder "../source/www/source_cron", "/home/html/public_html"
```

When I run my debugger any files associated with the source_cron are skipped even though the code is running them.

I figured that is has to to with the port but I don't know for sure. I wanted to know if it is possible to listen to the cron mapping and what would I have to do?